# How can I line up my DIVs with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have been given the following:

```
<div class="elf">Label 1</div>
<div class="eff">Data 1</div>

<div class="elf">Label 2</div>
<div class="eff">Data 2</div>

<div class="elf">Label 3</div>
<div class="eff">Data 3</div>
```

What I need to do is to have the labels and data line up something like below. Label on top, Data directly below and Label and Data flowing left and continue flowing left after my dialog width is filled:

```
Label 1      Label 2        Label 3
Data 1       Data 2         Data 3

...

Label 9      Label 10        Label 11
Data 9       Data 10         Data 11
```

I tried a lot of different combinations of CSS but can't get anything like this to appear. Here's my latest CSS which doesn't work:

```
.elf { margin: 1em 0 0 0; float: left; }
.eff { margin: 0.5em 0 0 0; display: block;  }
```

Can someone give me some advice on this? [Link to fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fn5H8/)

Please note I can't really add anything more to the HTML. All I can do is to change the CSS for this application.

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you change the html?

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML. That's why I am asking if there is a CSS solution that doesn't involve a wrapper. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you cannot change the html in anyway (which you really should if you can), and can only edit css, you can do so with the following (assuming labels have a FIXED width):

```
.elf { margin: 0 0 0 0; display: inline-block;}
.eff { margin-left: -3em; display: inline-block; position: relative; direction: ltr; top: 1em;}
```

If you can change the html, this would make it a lot easier:

```
<div style="float:left">
    <div class="elf">Label 1</div>
    <div class="eff">Data 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In addition, if you can use Javascript, you can easily change it around to make it easier :)

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the idea of using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have data which would lend it self properly to a table so that may be your best bet. But otherwise just make a wrapper around your label and data.

```
<style>
  .box {
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
  }
  .label, .data {
    display:block;
  }
</style>

<div class="box">
  <div class="label">
    Label 1
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    Data 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but do think there is a way this could be done without changing the HTML and adding a wrapper. I don't really have any access to the HTML and can't change it as it is used as is for a different view. Changing the HTML will be a problem for the other view.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure CSS solution that does not alter the source HTML, you could try

```
.elf{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  margin-bottom:2em;
}

.eff{
  position:relative;
  left:-100px;
  top:1em;
  width:1px;
  overflow:visible;
  white-space:nowrap;
  float:left;
}
```